# ros package change to install folder when do command catkin_make install

Tags: ros, catkin-make, package

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I create ros package named pioneer3at_gazebo in catkin_ws/src;
then I do catkin_make install; when i use roscd pioneer3at_gazebo, the path show in catkin_make/install.
why that happen?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/205422/ros-package-change-to-install-folder-when-do-command-catkin_make-install/) by [crazymumu](https://answers.ros.org/users/21710/crazymumu/) on ROS Answers with karma: 214 on 2015-03-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

What did you expect would happen?

`catkin_make install` does just what it says: it *makes* (builds) things first,then *installs* them into the default location (which is `/path/to/catkin_ws/install`).

If you then do `source /path/to/catkin_ws/install/setup.bash`, your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` is set to include locations under `/path/to/catkin_ws/install`, so a `roscd PKG` will take you there, instead of `devel/`.

---

For some more info, see [catkin/workspaces](http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/workspaces) on the ROS wiki. I think especially the *Catkin Workspaces* section should be helpful.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2015-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1